# Is there a way to stop VS Code Remote SSH from failing after it is disconnected?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, remote-access

I find that if I leave my VS Code Remote SSH connection open it disconnects automatically after a certain amount of time.  Following automatic disconnection I find the Remote SSH then fails:  when I try to log in again I get repeated requests for my remote password and every time I enter my password I just get another password prompt.

My current workaround is to go to the Command Palette and do "Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host".  Sometimes I need to do this multiple times for it to take effect.  Then when I next log in there is a lengthy VS Code installation script that needs to run before I can start coding again.

Is there a way of setting up VS Code Remote SSH that avoids this issue?  I have tried some of the suggestions on this page - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting.  However I feel like I am completely in the dark regarding what the underlying issue is.  I do not even know how I could go about generating informative diagnostics / a log.

Comment: have you found a resolution? I am struggling with this issue at the moment.

Comment: No!  I found this issue sufficiently irritating that I would probably avoid using VS Code for remote development work on my MacBook in the future.  I think emacs is still well supported on Mac.  And obviously if you can find a way of keeping your work local then that could be a workaround.  In the last year I have found myself making quite liberal use of the command `scp -r` to copy a whole directory of work from local to remote or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the remote machine has a limited number of proccess to run at same time. When a automatic disconnection of vscode happen, the that session is still running, but you cannot create a new one because you are over the limit in number of process.

In my case, asking to the remote machine to kill my process (manually done by the technician working in that machine in this case) works.

A better solution will be close the vscode sessions from your machine, to be able to start a new one again.

Comment: Nice adding some insight. (I removed the non-answering part, to protect you from giving the wrong impression of only saying "me too".)

Comment: I posted this question a while ago and am now using a different local machine for development work and also different remote machines.  Re. local machine, previously I was using a MacBook M1, now I am using a Lenovo with Windows 10 OS.  I have found that I no longer suffer the same issue so either it is Mac-specific, or there have been updates to VS Code that fix this issue.  I found it so irritating at the time that I reverted to using emacs for remote development work, as that did not have the same issue.